# Использование готовой базы данных SQLite android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне необходимо выводить данные в listView (а лучше в RecycleView) из уже готовой базы данных SQLite.
Пыталась следовать инструкции из видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLnVhgYdVd8
Но при запуске приложения оно у меня вылетает.

Вот мой код...
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lvProduct;
private ListProductAdapter adapter;
private List<Product> mProductList;
private DataBaseHelper mDBHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_product);
    mDBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    //Проверка на существование БД
    File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists())
    {
        mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Копирование БД
        if(copyDataBase(this))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    //Получаем данные из БД если она не пустая и выводи ее в нашем activity_main
    mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();
    //В этом адаптере
    adapter = new ListProductAdapter(this, mProductList);
    //Вывести адптер на наш listView
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private boolean copyDataBase(Context context)
{
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DataBaseHelper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DataBaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DataBaseHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("MainActivity", "DB copied");
        return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

DataBaseHelper:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DBNAME = "sample.sqlite";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/databases";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void openDataBase()
{
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (mDataBase != null && mDataBase.isOpen())
    {
        return;
    }
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDataBase()
{
    if(mDataBase!=null)
    {
        mDataBase.close();
    }
}

public List<Product> getListProduct()
{
    Product product = null;
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDataBase();
    Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        product = new Product(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2), cursor.getString(3));
        productList.add(product);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDataBase();
    return productList;
}
```

}
ListProductAdapter:

```
public class ListProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Product> mProductList;

public ListProductAdapter(Context mContext, List<Product> mProductList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mProductList = mProductList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mProductList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mProductList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mProductList.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_listview, null);
    TextView tvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
    TextView tvPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_price);
    TextView tvDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_description);
    tvName.setText(mProductList.get(position).getName());
    tvPrice.setText(String.valueOf(mProductList.get(position).getPrice()) + "$");
    tvDescription.setText(mProductList.get(position).getDescription());
    return v;
}
```

}

И непосредственно Product:

```
public class Product {
private  int id;
private String name;
private int price;
private String description;

public Product(int id, String name, int price, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

При запуске приложения в логах следующая ин-ция:

```
2020-04-28 23:12:17.886 12730-12730/com.example.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: PRODUCT
```

2020-04-28 23:12:17.889 12730-12730/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12730
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PRODUCT (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PRODUCT (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
        at com.example.myapplication.database.DataBaseHelper.getListProduct(DataBaseHelper.java:58)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
Ругается он непосредственно на строку в MainActivity:

```
  mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();
```

В DataBaseHelper:

```
Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT", null);
```

Comment: добавьте код какой-то, то что у вас есть, покажите ошибку, так сложно помочь

Comment: Добавила информацию из Logcat

Comment: а код активности где ошибка происходит?

Comment: В mainActivity строка на которую ссылается ошибка следующая:
  //Получаем данные из БД если она не пустая 
        mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();

Comment: А в DataBaseHelper :
 public List<Product> getListProduct()
    {
        Product product = null;
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        { product = new Product(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2), cursor.getString(3));
            productList.add(product);
            cursor.moveToNext();}
        cursor.close();
        closeDataBase();
        return productList;
    }

Comment: Причем ругается именно на строку
  Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT", null);

Comment: вы можете эту информацию добавить в тело вопроса, как и логи, чтобы все всем было видно пожалуйста?)

Comment: Конечно, я вот сейчас думаю, может лучше создать новый вопрос с сылкой на этот и в нем полностью привести тот код, что у меня вышел вместе с информацией из логов?

Comment: не нужно плодить море вопросов, просто структурировано все расскажите и покажите код :)

Comment: Я обновила описание

Answer (score 2):

Я не смотрел видеоурок, но расскажу вам

1 Для работой с готовой базой данных проще всего воспользоваться отличным решением для этого - библиотекой SQLiteAssetsHelper [тыц](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Суть ее работы в том, что при первом запуске она распаковывается автоматически. Для этого саму базу нужно положить в папку assets/databases , сам файл должен иметь вид `my_database.db` все это конечно можно сделать и ручками но так реально проще.

Далее стоит создать класс управления базы данных и унаследовать его от самого хэлпера

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper
```

Для работы базе данных нужен контекст.

Вот пример самого класса.

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

```
private static final String TAG = "TAG";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 

private static String DATABASE_NAME = "database_1.db";

private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;


public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    try {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        try {
            clearDB();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            setForcedUpgrade();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "MyDatabase: " + e);
    }
}

//  ПОЛУЧИТЬ все элементы
public Cursor getAllData(String table_name) {
    myDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
    return myDataBase.query(
        table_name, null, null, null, null, null, null
    );
}





public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}



public void clearDB() {
    if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen()) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    File file = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
    SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(file);
}
```

}

Соответственно где то в активити вам нужно создать обьект базы данных
например

```
MyDatabase myDataBase = new MyDatabase(context)
```

и сделать запрос который вернет список

```
private List<Bus_List> busLists = new ArrayList<>();

 public List<Bus_List> retrieveAllData() {
        Cursor cursor = database.getAllData(TABLE_BUS);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long _id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String bus_number = cursor.getString(1);
            String start_station = cursor.getString(2);
            String end_station = cursor.getString(3);
            Bus_List busList = new Bus_List(bus_number, start_station, end_station);
            busLists.add(busList);
        }
        database.closeDB();
        return busLists;
    }
```

Или так

```
if(getActivity()!= null){
     database = ((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getDatabase();
     retriever = new Retriever(database);`



  public Retriever(MyDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
    }
```

И полученный список запихнуть в адаптер

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Можете поподробнее рассказать сколько java class у меня должно быть?
Только MyDatabase.java и соответственно MainActivity?
Или должен быть еще класс?

Comment: Если исходить из минимуиа, то вам нужна pojo model, акьивити фрагмени и собственно база данных

Comment: То есть получается необходимо DataBase.java (управление БД) и активность. 
А так же я сделала 2 разметки, на activity_main.xml  у меня указан просто List_view  в котором будут выводиться данные из бд, а на example_layout.xml  у меня проставлен один TextView (как будет выглядеть один элемент из списка).
Далее как и указанно у вас я в моем DataBase унаследовала класс от хелпера и прописала как будут получаться данные, условия закрытия БД и условие очистки.

Comment: Далее я не очень понимаю. Мне необходимо в MainActivity объявить объект базы данных. А запрос который вернет список мне прописывать в MainActivity  в onCreate?

Comment: Вам необходимо создать базу данных, потом создать экземпляр класса в активити, И далее обращаться к нему кк только угодно. Сами запросы же можно размещать где вам угодно. Если приложение небольшое то можно прямо в базе или на месте в активити, если запросов много, можно создать отдельный класс для них итд/ Я если честно, не совсем помню что такое ListView, попробуйте RecyclerView